# Do static methods invoked by EJBs participate in transactions

Tags: java, transactions, ejb, static-methods

I know that having transaction attribute on a static method inside an EJB is incorrect. There won't be any exception thrown but the transaction attribute will not have any effect.

However, if an EJB has a method callMe() with a transaction attribute (let's say REQUIRED) and this method invokes a static method that is within the same EJB or another helper class, will the static method be part of the container transaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it will be inside the transaction. The transaction is open for that entire method and anything called inside of it will execute inside the transaction unless you use special transaction attribute methods like : NOT_SUPPORTED or REQUIRES_NEW obviously.

Comment: The thing is that, by the [EJB specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/ejb-3_2-fr-spec/index.html), transaction attributes shouldn't be placed on static methods.

Comment: the question is not related to that though, he is asking if he can invoke a static method from a non-static transactional method inside an ejb which he can safely do but best make the method private to not confuse anyone

Comment: That's not the question the OP has made. The question is "...will the static method be part of the container transaction?". And the answer is no.

Comment: No the question op made is in the question: "However, if an EJB has a method callMe() with a transaction attribute (let's say REQUIRED) and this method invokes a static method that is within the same EJB or another helper class, will the static method be part of the container transaction?" 
I suggest you become a politician

Comment: I totally understand the question. There's no need for you to repost it as a comment. Now, do you understand it? Because, from your answer, it doesn't seem so. Notice that the user **is not** asking, as you said in one of your previous comments, "*...if he can invoke a static method from a non-static transactional method inside an EJB...*". That's not his question at all. He wants to know if the static method will be taken into account during the container-managed transaction demarcation.

Comment: He is not asking that, he already knows that which is clear from the question as he states it in the beginning: "I know that having transaction attribute on a static method inside an EJB is incorrect. There won't be any exception thrown but the transaction attribute will not have any effect."
Anyway im out, not going to fight dyslexia on stackoverflow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107418/discussion-between-aribeiro-and-highstakes).

Answer (score 0):

When one talks about EJBs, one talk about beans' instances and not about the class itself.

Furthermore, in an enterprise bean with container-managed transaction demarcation, the EJB container sets the boundaries of the transactions associated to the bean instance, either session or message-driven.

Finally, as the [EJB 3.2 spec](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/ejb-3_2-fr-spec/index.html) states, since the transaction attributes for the methods of a bean class may be specified on the class, the business
methods of the class, or both, and these methods can't be static, any static methods declared on the bean will not take part on the container-managed transactions.

As a side note, on the *Revision History* section of the EJB 3.2 specification (part *A.8 Final Release Candidate*), is mentioned the following:

> *Clarified that no-interface view and no-methods interface message listener methods are non-static public methods*